# Which dimensionality reduction technique preserves the k nearest neighbors (euclidean space)?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, k-nearest-neighbour, multidimensional-scaling, euclidean

I'm looking for a lower dimensional projection of data such that the k nearest neighbors (in Euclidean space) in high dimensions remain the k nearest neighbors in low dimensions. I found that Isomap takes k-neighborhood into account, but it looks at gedesic distance rather than Eucledian distance, right? What about Multidimensional scaling (MDS)? Or should I use t-SNE or LLE?

Comment: As far as I know t-SNE doesn't guarantee conserving neighbourhood, since it uses a "spring"-type distance model, i.e. distances can be compressed/extended a lot depending on context.

Comment: Can you give a dummy problem?  Can you motivate the problem?  How about providing links to references in the "jargon" that was used?  Is this a dead question?